# Sorting columns with pivot table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting, pivot

I would like to sort my columns in pivot table. Here is a [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1628f/2/1) to my example table and query what i have now. As you can see in result the name of the columns are unsorted.

I'm basically doing this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
     CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN DATE(date) = ''', date,
            ''' THEN score END) `', DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d.%m.%Y'), '`'))
INTO @sql
FROM tabletest
ORDER BY date;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT name,', @sql, ' 
                 FROM tabletest
                GROUP BY name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

My column output is like this:

```
|    NAME | 30.11.2013 | 28.11.2013 | 27.11.2013 | 29.11.2013 |
|---------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
|   Adele |        234 |        552 |     (null) |     (null) |
```

And I would like to have the columns sorted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an `ORDER BY date` inside the `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
     CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN DATE(date) = ''', date,
            ''' THEN score END) `', DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d.%m.%Y'), '`')
            ORDER BY date)
```

Comment: +1 @Mosty Mostacho this is indeed the way to go... Bushwacka side note  you also want want to enlarge group_concat_max_len (SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = ?? because it defualt size is 1024 bytes) setting because you can miss date columns if you dont... to make it more nasty MySQL wont give an error..  see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len

Comment: Yes, in my real query i have the group_concat_max_len function.